# passing values of an array to a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
     System.out.print("How many grades does the student have for semester " + (i+1) + ": "); 
     gradeAmt = keyboard.nextInt();

     while(gradeAmt <= 1)
      {
      System.out.println("You need to enter at least two grades.");
      System.out.print("Enter again: ");
      gradeAmt = keyboard.nextInt();
      }
     int[] gradeArray = new int[gradeAmt];

     for(int k = 0; k < gradeArray.length; k++)
        {   
        System.out.print("Enter test " + (k+1) + ": ");
         gradeArray[k] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
  }
```

Looking at this chunk of code, I would like to pass the values of the tests in both quarters to a method to be turned into letter grades. For instance, if the test values for semester 1 are 90 and 80, and the values for semester 2 are 90 and 60, I want the method to return that 2 A's, 1 B, and 1 D were the grades for the year.
How would i go about passing the inputs of both semesters to the method?

The full code can be viewed at http://pastebin.com/ER2kEwA5
and my attempt at creating the method is on line 56 (P.S i know its terrible)

Comment: what is semesters in above code?

Comment: It sounds like you simply need to do exactly what you said. Is it the syntax that eludes you?

Comment: Can you please post the number-grade to letter-grade method?  It's hard to know what problem you are having with code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

To turn the numbers into letters you could use something like this:

```
char[] gradeLetters = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
int[] count = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
 for(int k = 0; k < gradeArray.length; k++)
 {   
      int gradeIndex = (100 - gradeArray[k])/10;
      count[gradeIndex]++;
 }
```

To print out the letter just use:

```
 for(int k = 0; k < count.length; k++){
      if(count[k] == 1)      
        System.out.printline("1 "+ gradeLetters[k]);
      else if(count[k] > 1)
        System.out.printline(count[k]+" "+gradeLetters[k]+"'s");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to submit (and return) all the values.

```
char[] getGrades(int[] score) {
    char[] grades = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    char[] retVal = new char[score.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        retVal[i] = grades[Math.min(5,(9 - (score[i] / 10)))];
    }
    return retVal;
}
```